# What does it mean when a function has two square brackets?

Tags: differential-equations, functions, syntax

I have been solving some partial differential equations with mathematica, and the solution of one involves a function $c_1$ as follows,

$f[x,y,z]=e^{x}c_1[y][y+xz].$

I am not sure exactly what it means when there are two brackets in a function definiton. If I want to make use of this result, what exactly is this syntax telling me about the function $c_1$?

Many thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

The equation that outputs the kind of function I am talking about is,

```
eqn = n z_n D[X[x, y, z_n, q_n], q_n]- x D[X[x, y, z_n, q_n,] y] + C_1 X[x, y,z_n, q_n];

DSolve[eqn == 0, X[x, y, z_n, q_n, {x, y, z_n, q_n}]
    {{X[x, y, z_n, q_n] -> E^((y C_1)/x) C[1][x, z_n][(x q_n + n z_n y)/x]}}
```

Comment: First c1 operates on y, giving a new function, say g, then g operates on y+xz,  The function is ['curried'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). See the documentation for [`Construct`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Construct.html) and [`OperatorApplied`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OperatorApplied.html).

Comment: Consider `f[x_] := Function[{n}, n + x]` - Then `g = f[2]` gives you a function `Function[{n$}, n$ + 2]`, and `g[3]` gives you 2+3 = 5. Instead of doing that step by step, `f[2][3]` achieves the same thing.

Comment: I see, so it doesn't tell me anything about the structure of the function, for example if there is a quadratic dependence on x, or a term involving a fraction of two parameters etc. ?

Comment: As it's a differential equation solution, $c_1$ is a [generated parameter](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeneratedParameters.html). In this context it just means it's any function of y and y+xz I think. Direct example: https://wolfram.com/xid/0g7izfto3fn-ilsydr

Comment: Yes, so that is what confuses me; with a single bracket f[y+xz] I can understand that f is some function of y+xz, but f[y][y+xz] doesn't seem to be the same as say f[y,y+xz] right ?

Comment: Yes, but you can write f[y][y+xz] as h[y,y+xz] for some other function h. Going back to the example above `f[x_] := Function[{n}, n + x]` we could also write a function `h[x_,n_]:=n+x` and h[2,3] would be equivalent to f[2][3]. In your problem you could also think of $c_1$ as any $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ function and it's saying you must evaluate it at {y,y+xz}

Comment: Ok, so if I want to put the above solution into a further differential equation, can I then write $f[x,y,z]=e^{x}c_2[y,y+xz]$ ?

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: Why not include the `DSolve[]` that generated the expression you are mystified with?

Comment: Should all the `_n` that follow the variables `z` and `q` be deleted?  Also there are some missing `]`; and the second `D` in `eqn` is missing the variable with respect to which `X` is to be differentiated (or maybe it's just missing a `]`).  Finally don't use `C` as a variable/parameter. It's a protected system symbol.

Comment: It's saying the solution if is $X = e^{{C_1 y}/{x}} f (x, z; u) $, where $u = ({n y z + q x})/{x} $ and $f (x, z; u) $ is a $C^1$ function of $u$ in which $x$ and $z$ are free parameters.

Comment: @MichaelE2, sorry yes I did a bad job copying my Mathematica script. The z_n etc should just mean $z_n$, and the second derivative should be with respect to y. I suppose then this makes solving for this function complicated? As in if I put this into a further differential equation.

Comment: Execute `FullForm[z_n]` to see what it is.  The underscore in Mathematica represent a pattern called `Blank[]`, not a subscript as in TeX.  Typically, users represent $z_n$ by `z[n]` in code, though just using `z` here seems better to me. -- As for solving, the code does not work with `z_n` in it; I get an error: "DSolve::dsvar: z_n cannot be used as a variable."